# UITableView edit mode shifting of cell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` with a custom cell and a custom button for the entering the edit mode as well as a custom accessory button. Everything is working but I want the `UIImageView` with two other `UILabels` adjacent to it  within the cell to be at its X position but only want the "ADD QTY" `UILabel` to shift its X position to make room for the accessory button.

[image: Tableview upon entering edit mode.]

Comment: You need to work on layoutsubviews method of your custom cell

Comment: Don't subviews move in editing when they are added to the cells content view? Couldn't you just add everything apart from the quantity label to the cells view, and not content view?

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want the contents of the `UITableViewCell` to shift, implement the method

```
- tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:
```

and make it return `NO`. This method is a part of `UITableViewDelegate`.

---

To make the **ADD QTY** move left, you will need to make a custom animation, I think. Animate the label for **ADD QTY** in this method

```
- tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666185/custom-uitableviewcell-in-edit-mode-does-not-move-my-uilabels). Check it out and tell me if it works. Cheers!